# There exists a surjective homomorphism $C_{24}\times C_{18} \to C_{16}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> There exists a surjective homomorphism $C_{24}\times C_{18} \to C_{16}$?

I'm not sure how to tackle this one. My bet was to prove that it doesn't exist (I maybe be wrong).

So far I have two different approach. I've had a hard time making sense of the basic results of my Abstract Algebra course, so if one of my approaches is incorrect I would appreciate if someone could point out why.

**1st approach:**

Let suppose the surjective homomorphism exists. Then we also have that $\exists \ \phi:  C_16 \to  C_{24}\times C_{18}$.

Let $a \in C_{16}: a^{16} = e_{C_{16}}$ and $(c, d)^k \in C_{24}\times C_{18}: c C_{24}$ and $d \in C_{18}$. Then under action of $\phi$ we have

\begin{align}
(c,d)^{16k} &= \phi(a)^{16}\\
&= \phi(a^{16})\\
&= \phi(e_{C_{16}})\\
&= e_{C_{24} \times C_{18}}
\end{align}

But this contradicts the fact that, since $\mathrm{gcd}(24,18) \neq 1, C_{24}\times C_{18}$ is not cyclic. Therefore, such surjective homomorphism does not exist.

**2nd approach:**

Under surjection we have that every element of $C_{16}$ is map to a single, unique element of $C_{24}\times C_{18}$, which means that $|C_{16}| = |C_{24}\times C_{18}|$. But $|C_{16}| = 16 \neq |C_{24}\times C_{18}| = |C_{24}||C_{18}| = 24\cdot 18$. So such a surjective homomorphism does not exist.

Comment: existence of a surjective homomorphism does not imply existence of $\phi$ in your first approach (that would also require injectivity), nor does it imply that $|C_{16}|=|C_{24}\times C_{18}|$, again for this you would also need injectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

$C_{24}\times C_{18}$ has exponent $lcm(24,18)=72$, that is, $x^{72}=1$ for all $x \in C_{24}\times C_{18}$ .

Therefore, every homomorphic image of $C_{24}\times C_{18}$ has exponent a divisor of $72$.

But $C_{16}$ has exponent $16$, which is not a divisor of $72$.

Answer (score 4):

Both of your approaches are not correct. As Robert commented, the existence of a surjective homomorphism does not guarantee an inverse map.

For example the projection $C_2\times C_2 \to C_2$ is surjective, can you apply either of your approaches?

---

Hint: Does $C_{24}\times C_{18}$ have any elements of order $16$? How about $C_{16}$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking: $C_{24}\times C_{18}$ has a element of order $16$ if $16k \equiv\ 0\ \mathrm{mod}\ 432$ or $k \equiv 0\ \mathrm{mod}\ 27$. there are $16$ such elements, which can be written as $a = 27k : 0 \leq k < 16, k\in \mathbb{N_0}$.

Comment: @Jazz Be careful! $C_{24}\times C_{18}\not\simeq C_{432}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are mistaking :p. You are talking about $C_{432}$ not $C_{24}\times C_{18}$, which is *not* cyclic as you said in your 2nd approach.

Comment: I'm lost ):. Frankly I don't know how to go about proving the existence of a surjective homomorphism.

Comment: As others have hinted at, there is no such surjective homomorphism because $C_{24} \times C_{18}$ has no element of order $16$.